# TikZposter leaves a gap in empty innerblock title

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, tikzposter

As an example, I've included a TikZPoster block I've created below. Notice the white gaps in between the blue innerblocks. Normally, the innerblock background colors alternate between blue and white, meaning that white innerblocks appear larger. I've concluded that this white gap is an artifact of having no innerblocktitle, because if I draw nothing over it looks like this:

```
\draw[draw=none, fill=innerblockbodybgcolor]
             (innerblockbody.south west) rectangle (innerblockbody.north east);
```

[image: Title gaps]

In contrast, if I do draw over the the title area the gap goes away (but the innerblock's contents are not visually centered anymore):

```
\draw[draw=none, fill=innerblockbodybgcolor]
             (innerblockbody.south west) rectangle (innerblocktitle.north east);
```

[image: Filled title gaps]

This space is worthless for me as I have other means of creating text separation. 
The gap is still visible whenever I use `\useinnerblockstyle{Minimal}` (or the Basic class, for that matter) and `\useblockstyle{Basic}`. How can I disable it? It takes up unnessecary room and makes images appear off-center if I try to fill the space up as in my last provided image.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0pt, innermargin=40pt, colspace=50pt, blockverticalspace=50pt]{tikzposter}

% dummy text generation
\usepackage{lipsum}

% based on "Minimal" blockstyle
\defineblockstyle{Minimal2}{
    titlewidthscale=1, bodywidthscale=1, titlecenter,
    titleoffsetx=0pt, titleoffsety=0pt, bodyoffsetx=0pt, bodyoffsety=0pt,
    bodyverticalshift=0pt, roundedcorners=6, linewidth=0.42cm,
    titleinnersep=1cm, bodyinnersep=0.00cm}
{
    \begin{scope}[line width=\blocklinewidth, rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners]
           % title rectangle
           \draw[draw=none, fill=blue]
               (blocktitle.south west) rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
           % box outline
           \draw[color=blue, fill=none]
               (blockbody.south west) rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
    \end{scope}
}

% based on "Minimal" innerblockstyle
\defineinnerblockstyle{MinimalInner}{
    titlewidthscale=1, bodywidthscale=1, titlecenter,
    titleoffsetx=0pt, titleoffsety=-0pt, bodyoffsetx=0pt, bodyoffsety=90pt,
    bodyverticalshift=0pt, roundedcorners=0, linewidth=0.0cm,
    titleinnersep=0pt, bodyinnersep=25pt
}{
    \begin{scope}[line width=\innerblocklinewidth, rounded corners=\innerblockroundedcorners]
       \ifInnerblockHasTitle %
           \draw[draw=none, fill=blue]
               (innerblockbody.south west) rectangle (innerblocktitle.north east);
       \else
             \draw[draw=none, fill=blue]
                 (innerblockbody.south west) rectangle (innerblockbody.north east);
        \fi
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\usebackgroundstyle{Default}
\useblockstyle{Minimal2}
\useinnerblockstyle{MinimalInner}

\block{BLOCKTITLE}{\innerblock{}{\lipsum[1]} \innerblock{}{\lipsum[1]}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be nice to have a Minimal Working Example (that is a code snippet which can be compiled and shows your problem). As such, it is a bit difficult to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I've added a MWE that shows the gaps I want to get rid of.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don’t just write `\draw[color=blue, fill=blue] (blockbody.south west) rectangle (blocktitle.north east);` to fill the whole block body with your desired background color and not just each single innerblock?

Comment: Yes, as stated in my question, I normally alternate the innerblock backgrounds between white and blue. The images just serve as a clear demonstration of the gaps that appear.

Comment: I see. This is really strange. You could use `titleoffsety=-10pt` in `\defineinnerblockstyle` as a workaround.

Comment: Yeah, it seems kinda like a bug/oversight. Your proposal about does it, but leaves like 1pt of space between the innerblocks. Oddly enough, increasing `titleoffsety` way above -10pt changes nothing in my MWE/project (and still leaves the small ~1pt gap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you describe probably comes from the fact that, in the `tikzposter` document class, a node called `innerblocktitle` is defined at the position where the inner block title should appear. This node, however, is always defined, even if  the inner block title is empty. The bug here is, that nodes have an `inner sep` by default, which is obviously causing this strange space you notive.

In the code below, I use the package `xpatch` to append the style `inner sep=0pt` to this node. This removes the spacing. Further, in order to minimise the tiny space between adjacent inner blocks (which I assume is due to rounding errors), you may want to add a blue border around the inner blocks in the same color as the background.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait, margin=0pt, innermargin=40pt, colspace=50pt, blockverticalspace=50pt]{tikzposter}

% dummy text generation
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\innerblock}{\node[minimum width=\TP@innerblocktitlewidth, minimum height=\TP@innerblocktitleheight, anchor=center] (innerblocktitle)}{\node[inner sep=0pt, minimum width=\TP@innerblocktitlewidth, minimum height=\TP@innerblocktitleheight, anchor=center] (innerblocktitle)}{}{}
\makeatother

% based on "Minimal" blockstyle
\defineblockstyle{Minimal2}{
    titlewidthscale=1, bodywidthscale=1, titlecenter,
    titleoffsetx=0pt, titleoffsety=0pt, bodyoffsetx=0pt, bodyoffsety=0pt, 
    bodyverticalshift=0pt, roundedcorners=6, linewidth=10pt,
    titleinnersep=1cm, bodyinnersep=0.00cm}
{
    \begin{scope}[line width=\blocklinewidth, rounded corners=\blockroundedcorners]
           % title rectangle
           \fill[blue]
               (blocktitle.south west) rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
           % box outline
           \draw[blue]
               (blockbody.south west) rectangle (blocktitle.north east);
    \end{scope}
}

% based on "Minimal" innerblockstyle
\defineinnerblockstyle{MinimalInner}{
    titlewidthscale=1, bodywidthscale=1, titlecenter,
    titleoffsetx=0pt, titleoffsety=0pt, bodyoffsetx=0pt, bodyoffsety=90pt,
    bodyverticalshift=0pt, roundedcorners=0, linewidth=0.0cm,
    titleinnersep=0pt, bodyinnersep=25pt
}{
    \begin{scope}[line width=\innerblocklinewidth, rounded corners=\innerblockroundedcorners]
       \ifInnerblockHasTitle%
           \filldraw[blue]
               (innerblockbody.south west) rectangle (innerblocktitle.north east);
       \else
           \filldraw[blue]
               (innerblockbody.south west) rectangle (innerblockbody.north east);
        \fi
    \end{scope}
}

\begin{document}

\usebackgroundstyle{Default}
\useblockstyle{Minimal2}
\useinnerblockstyle{MinimalInner}

\block{BLOCKTITLE}{\innerblock{}{\lipsum[1]}\innerblock{}{\lipsum[1]}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the tiny space went away on it's own after your xpatch fix. Thank you!